# Does Breeze.js support querying for entities with an empty one-to-many navigation property?

Tags: breeze

If we have entities `Customer` and `Order`, and `Customer` has a collection `Orders`, is it possible to build a query for customers with no orders using Breeze?

OData/WebApi supports this using `not Orders/any()`, and I can successfully execute such a query using `EntityManager.executeQuery(string)`.  Is it possible to build this query using `Predicate` instead of manually building the OData query string?  e.g. Something like `Predicate.create("Orders", "any").not()` (which doesn't work in 1.4.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, you can accomplish the same effect by comparing any nonnullable column with null in the 'any' subquery. For example:

```
var p = Predicate.create("orders", "any", "rowVersion", "!=", null).not();
var query = EntityQuery.from("Customers").where(p).expand("orders");
```

We will take a look at being able to remove the 2nd predicate in the next release.